# Variance pooling in Cohen's d

Tags: variance, effect-size, cohens-d

I have a question about the use of pooled variance in Cohen's d effect size metric. Pooled variance assumes both samples are coming from populations of same variance. They quantified this as no one sample std is more than twice the other. The question is, do I always use pooled variance in Cohen's d calculation, even if the pooling assumption is not valid ? And if not what to replace pooled variance with ? Or I have to use other metric for calculating effect size ?